# Possible HTML Encoding issue with Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, mailgun

I'm trying to use the MailGun API to enable batch sending. My use case is notifying users of "jobs" and the match could be anywhere from a few to thousands.

I'm getting an unhelpful error from the MailGun site

> unable to parse request: invalid URL escape "%' "

The message body only contains this type of instance in CSS eg: 'width: 100%'. Ideally there will be some "*recipient-variables*" included but I removed them for troubleshooting. This ONLY causes a problem when run from code - I can use Postman to post the content and get no errors.

```
{"from":"Jeff <no-reply@jeffrose.ca>","to":["Jeff <jeff+2@jeffrose.ca>","Mark <jeff+1@jeffrose.ca>"],"subject":"Simple test","html":"<html>Let's try <span style='width:80%'>this</span></html>","recipient-variables":{"jeff+1@jeffrose.ca":{"email":"jeff+1@jeffrose.ca","position":"President","talentname":"Mark Smith"}},"o:tag":"interview-request"}
```

When I strip out all of my content, the message then says "from parameter is missing" when it clearly isn't.

```
{"from":"Jeff <no-reply@jeffrose.ca>","to":["Jeff <jeff+2@jeffrose.ca>","Mark <jeff+1@jeffrose.ca>"],"subject":"Simple test","html":"<html>Let's try this</html>","recipient-variables":{"jeff+1@jeffrose.ca":{"email":"jeff+1@jeffrose.ca","position":"President","talentname":"Mark Smith"}},"o:tag":"interview-request"}
```

Sending Code:

```
Function generalEmailMailGun(theseParams)
        Dim httpPostData
        Dim mailGunMessageUrl
        Const MAILGUN_BASE_URL = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/secretdomain.com"
        Const MAILGUN_API_KEY = "MY API KEY IS CORRECT"

        httpPostData = httpPostData & theseParams

        set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        mailGunMessageUrl = MAILGUN_BASE_URL & "/messages"
        http.Open "POST", mailGunMessageUrl, false, "api", MAILGUN_API_KEY
        http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
        http.Send httpPostdata
        If http.status <> 200 Then
          Response.Write "An error occurred: " & http.responseText
        End If

        generalEmailMailGun = http.responseText
        Set http = Nothing

    end function
```

Any thoughts or assistance would be appreciated. I've banged my head against this for WAY too long.

Comment: You've posted JSON, but your code says `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not JSON; So what is it meant to be?

Comment: Do some names include an Apostrophe like in "O'Brien"?